# Meteor account password pattern

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I would like to change meteor account password pattern on signup. how and where add Regex to validate password filed? For example default password allows empty spaces. I want to change at least single text in password field

**Meteor packages:**

```
accounts-password
ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend using accounts-password past a prototype. There doesn't seem to be an independent repo detailing config options. There is a good alternative though: [user-accounts](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts).

This package is a lot easier to configure (here's the [guide](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/Guide.md)).

It just uses standard Object key/value config. You can attach a RegEx to any field, and do some reactive validation as well.